# How to measure performance of a Java application?

Tags: java, performance

I have a CPU intensive multi-threaded Java application and I'm looking for ways to measure its performance at run time (useful for automation). I tried a few options

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
System.nanoTime();
ThreadMXBean.getThreadCPUTime();
```

The first two measure real time. The last measures CPU time for only one thread. I want to measure the CPU-time for all threads spawned by the process.

Before resurrecting an old machine and dedicate it for this task, I would like to see what options I have now.

I run Linux and a platform dependent solution is acceptable, but least desirable.

Comment: See "Java theory and practice: Dynamic compilation and performance measurement" at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp12214/. It's a comment, not an answer :-)

Comment: Take a look at the source of this plugin - JTop : http://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/two_fine_demos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try perf4j: http://perf4j.codehaus.org/
I recommend using it along with AOP, but it's not a must. See http://perf4j.codehaus.org/devguide.html#Using_Spring_AOP_to_Integrate_Timing_Aspects for more details on AOP.

Comment: I'm pretty sure perf4j measures the realtime and not the CPU-time. I like the graphs though.

Comment: @Alexandru I believe this was the requirements. At least this is what I understand from the question...

Comment: You are right, I was not clear enough. The problem with realtime is that running times changes if I browse StackOverflow

Comment: LOL @Alexandru. No performance testing while you surf the net. At least not if you're using the same machine ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try to enable the JVM with Dtrace.
It has a lot of performance probes which help you get what ever you want.

Comment: Isn't Dtrace available only under Solaris?

Comment: Dtrace is available for openSolaris as well as Freebsd.One thing can be done is to get the java application on either of the OS just to do a performance of it and get the numbers.

Comment: Dtrace is also available on Mac OS X. But the Dtrace probes enabled in the Mac OS X JVM may differ from those enabled for Solaris.

Comment: @gaurav how ever intriguing the DTrace approach is, can it be used for anything highlevel or is it just for low-level stuff?